# Non-rectangular hitbox methods in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection

I'm creating a 2D top-down RPG, and many of my buildings/scenery have non-rectangular corners to the textures. Does anyone know a good way to create circular/triangular/polygonal hitboxes, or is too intensive too be worth it?

P.S. If it is too intensive, I can stick with rectangular hitboxes, no big deal.

Comment: Yeah this is all over the internet and not too expensive. This question is probably a duplicate, but you should search for Separating Axis Test. It gets more complicated than you'll probably want, so I recommend sticking with AABB hitboxes (like you said you can do) if you don't need anything more complex.

Comment: I'm willing to do complicated, but I don't need to implement it if I'm going to sacrifice performance for it. Is it bad for performance or does it not change it all that much?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Usually performance bottlenecks in terms of collision detection are due to a lack of broadphase :)

Comment: Alright, I think I'm going to make a go at it. Thanks for your help!